# DNS delegation from aws to oci

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

1. I have one domain say example.com which is hosted in aws.
2. Created one DNS-hosted zone in aws with the name example.com and created one NS record with the name dev.example.com which points to oracle DNS server ns1.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net., ns2.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net., ns3.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net., ns4.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net.
3. Created a hosted zone in OCI with the name dev.example.com which automatically created NS, and SOA records and manually created multiple records test1.dev.example.com and test2.dev.example.com. The NS rdata points to ns1.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net, ns2.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net,ns3.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net,ns4.p201.dns.oraclecloud.net

Getting unauthorized errors for creating SSL certificates to the records using Terraform. Is there any DNS delegation problem? If yes how to resolve the issue?